# Java- Scanner is not taking input

Tags: java, arrays, exception, sum

Here in this program I'm trying to get the sum of rows & columns of matrix.

This is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class RowSum {
int xin=0, run;
int [][]mun;int[] b;int[] c;

public void inputarray(int m,int n)
{
System.out.println("Enter number");
Scanner xam=new Scanner(System.in);
run=xam.nextInt();
mun[m][n]=run;
m--;n--;
if(n!=0 && m!=0)
{
inputarray(m,n);
}
xam.close();
}
public void sum_rows_columns(int m, int n){
b[xin]=0;c[xin]=0;
b[xin]=b[xin]+mun[m][n];
c[xin]=b[xin]+mun[n][m];        
++xin;
n--; m--;
if(n!=0 && m!=0)
{
sum_rows_columns(m,n);
}
}
public void PrintSumArray(int m,int n)
{
System.out.println("sum of" + xin + "row " +b[xin]);
System.out.println("sum of" + xin + "column " +c[xin]);
n--;
m--;
if(n!=0 && m!=0){
    PrintSumArray(m,n);
}
}
}
```

This is main class

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MatrixSum {

public static void main(String[] args){
int m,n;
String S1="Enter number of rows";
String S2="Enter number of columns";
System.out.println(S1);
Scanner inpu=new Scanner(System.in);
n=inpu.nextInt();
System.out.println(S2);
Scanner inp=new Scanner(System.in);
    m=inp.nextInt();
            inp.close();
            inpu.close();
RowSum RS=new RowSum(); 
RS.inputarray(m,n);
RS.sum_rows_columns(m,n);
RS.PrintSumArray(m,n);
        }
}
```

I'm trying to declare array in run time. When I tried to run it shows the following output in console:

Output:

Enter number of rows
   3
   Enter number of columns
   3
   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
   Scanner cannot be resolved to a type
   Scanner cannot be resolved to a type

```
at RowSum.inputarray(RowSum.java:10)
at MatrixSum.main(MatrixSum.java:18)
```

Comment: your java version? `version of Java before 1.5, java.util.Scanner doesn't exist.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the close

```
  inp.close();
  inpu.close();
```

at the very end of the main method. If your closing them before, causes System.in to be closed as well. This means that the Scanner has no way to ever read any data and thus throw the `NoSuchElementException`